# How can one seamlessly transfer services hosted on AWS to Google Cloud Platform and vice versa?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, cloud, google-cloud-storage

Last month there was an outage in AWS and some sites had to be taken down because of that. I was wondering if a company is availing both AWS and Google Cloud Platform for hosting, how easy would it be for them to easily transfer their services from the Amazon platform to the Google platform or vice versa ( In case Google Cloud has some outage) . First of all is it possible or not? And also if it's what would be the cost for performing such an activity and how much time will it take to get the services running back again.

In this I also did some digging up and what I came across was each of the providers (Google and Amazon) have tools of their own to do so i.e. for transferring the stored data from other platforms to their platform -
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/migrating?hl=en
https://aws.amazon.com/importexport/

Are these the only options available or there is anything else as well. Hope some AWS/Google cloud expert would be able to answer my question.

Comment: question is too broad. Of course one can switch service providers. the real question is cost. In an idea world you would use multiple cloud providers and failure of one of them would not impact you.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to run your application in both environments, keep the deployments in sync, keep the databases in sync, etc. That can get complicated and expensive...

Then to automatically fail over from one environment to another you could use a DNS service such as [DynDNS Active Failover](http://dyn.com/active-failover/) that monitors the health of your application and starts sending traffic to the other environment if your primary environment becomes unhealthy.

How you manage deployments, how you continually ship data across environments, how much all that will cost, all those questions are extremely specific to the technologies (programming languages, operating systems, database servers) you are currently using. There's no way to give details on how you would accomplish those tasks without having all the details of your system.

Further, if you are using proprietary technologies on a specific platform, such as Amazon Redshift or DynamoDB, you might not find a service on the other platform that provides the same functionality.

I've seen this subject come up a lot since the last AWS outage, but I think maintaining two environments on two different platforms is overkill for all but the most extremely critical applications. Instead, I would look into maintaining a copy of your application in a different AWS region, and use Route53 health checks to fail-over.